# UIProgressView with multiple colors

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create this type of UIProgressView:

[image: 3-color progress view]

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue? Please add some content to the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do. It looks you are displaying 2 separate values? (A red value and a dark gray value). Would the 2 track separately? What if the dark gray value is less than the red value? You need to define the problem much more clearly, and then you need to tell us what you've tried.

Answer (score -1):

You could put two progress bars on top of each other and set the top one's track colour to UIColor.clear